# How to decrease VTIME value with termios api in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, libraries, serial, tty

Related post closed with an open question. Why Windows is better than Linux for raw UART processing ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76979323/how-to-reduce-tty-vtime-for-non-canonical-uart-on-linux

Comment: Do you actually have Windows software that demonstrates this alleged capability is accurate? That is. do you understand the differences between *advertised* versus *measured*, and *accuracy* versus *precision*? IMO you need proper hardware support such as a UART with *receiver timeout* capability. Or a device driver targeted to solve this issue. Solutions that timestamp "arrival" of data are inadequate and inaccurate.

Comment: ReadIntervalTimeout : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddser/ns-ntddser-_serial_timeouts

Comment: PrimeCell UART (PL011) is mine

Comment: You're non-responsive. Apparently you don't understand the difference between *advertised* versus *measured* and *accuracy* versus *precision*. That Windows API merely advertises the specification of a timeout with millisec precision. That doesn't mean you will actually get that accuracy.  E.G. Warnings  from that doc "*the accuracy of the time-out measurement is limited by the granularity of the system clock*" and "*Time-outs might occur even later if system clock interrupt processing is delayed*".   What is the "*system clock*" rate?

Comment: https://youtu.be/g4sZUBS57OQ?feature=shared